# Generate random number in void that is called every frame

Tags: c#

I'm developing a plugin for GTA V with lspdfr api and there is a function called Progress that is called every frame and when I generate a random number in this function is always generating one but I only need it to generate once. Thanks.

```
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.API;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LSPD_First_Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.Callouts;
using LSPD_First_Response.Engine.Scripting.Entities;

namespace MetroCallouts3.Callouts{
public class example : Callout
{
public int i2;
public Random rnd2;
public int num2;
public override void Progress(){
for (int i2 = 0; i2 == 1; i2++)
            {
                rnd2 = new Random();
                num2 = rnd2.Next(1, 4);
            }
}
}
}
```

Comment: `and when I generate a random number in this function is always generating one but I only need it to generate once` this doesn't make a lot of sense and is confusing, please specify precisely (and unambiguously) what you actually need

Comment: Unsure what you're trying to accomplish - (a) your loop will never run as written, and (b) if you _"only need to generate once"_ then why even bother with a loop??